# Building a Client-Server Application and need help starting out

Tags: android, windows, server, client, instant-messaging

I am looking to make a messenging application for both Windows and Android over Wi-Fi. I have looked around for answers and have come back with a loads of articles that mention Client-Server applications, which is what I want to be using, but they do not mention clearly how everything works or where to start. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Extra Information:
If possible c# for the server-side as Im more skilled in c# than other languages although I don't mind learning a new one.

Articles I've Read:

http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-socket-programming.htm

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33396-basic-clientserver-chat-application-in-c%23/

Comment: Why not make a Web application? It handles your client server needs for both mobile and pc. Set up the we server on you local network and it's available to everyone behind your firewall. Set up an actual domain and Web page and it's available to the world. Though local network is easier and cheaper and can be done in c# / asp.net

Comment: One of the uses of this will be to send commands to-from both devices. Will I still able to send a command say from the mobile to the pc telling it to shutdown over the web application?

Comment: Yes that you can do through code and possibly impersonation though you'll be limited in what you can do on the client without a better client side -  better than a browser that is.